# How to draw a Pareto chart in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to implement Pareto chart using composite chart from dc.js. Composite sort works fine if the data coming in are linear rather than ordinal. I am stuck at implementing the following.

I have the following code, in this process I am trying to create pareto where on x axis **reasons** would sit and there are two y axis. One would represent the sum of the **time** and other would be the overall percentage **contribution** of the time

> total_time = sum(time)
>
> contribution = time/total_time

One chart is suppose to be sorted in ASC order one with the **time** value and one is suppose to be sorted in DESC order one with the **contribution**

What is the approach here ?

```
var sample_data = [
{ reason: "A", time: 1 },
{ reason: "B", time: 6 },
{ reason: "C", time: 6 },
{ reason: "D", time: 5 },
{ reason: "A", time: 5 },
{ reason: "B", time: 5 },
{ reason: "C", time: 8 },
{ reason: "A", time: 8 },
{ reason: "B", time: 2 },
{ reason: "C", time: 2 },
{ reason: "D", time: 10 },
{ reason: "C", time: 7 },
{ reason: "A", time: 3 },
{ reason: "B", time: 4 },
{ reason: "C", time: 2 }];
    
    
var ndx_ = crossfilter(sample_data),
dim_  = ndx_.dimension( function(d) {return d.reason;} ),
grp1_ = dim_.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.time;});
grp2_ = dim_.group().reduce(
  function(p,v){
    p.reason = v.reason;
    p.time = v.time;
    p.total_time += +p.time;
    p.contribution = p.time/p.total_time; 
   return p;
  },
function(p,v){
    p.reason = v.reason;
    p.time = v.time;
    p.total_time -= +p.time;
    p.contribution = p.time/p.total_time; 
  
  return p;
},
function(p,v){
  return {reason:'',time:0,total_time:0,contribution:0}
});
   
    
var sortByTime = sample_data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.time < b.time; });
var sampleDataSorted = sortByTime.map(function (d) { return d; });

chart
 .width(768)
        .height(480)
        //.x(d3.scaleBand())
                .x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(sampleDataSorted.map(function(d) {
                    console.log("asas",d);
                    return d.reason;
        })))

        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .yAxisLabel("The Y Axis")
        .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .compose([
            dc.barChart(chart)
                .dimension(dim_)
                            .barPadding(20)
                            .clipPadding(20)
                            .outerPadding(100)
                .group(grp1_, "Bars")
                            
                .centerBar(true) ,
                    dc.lineChart(chart) 
                .dimension(dim_)
                .colors('red')
                .group(grp2_, "Dots")
                .dashStyle([2,2])
                            .valueAccessor(function(d){return d.value.contribution})
            ])
.ordering(function(d) { return +d.time; })
        .brushOn(false)
        
 
    
        chart.render();
```

PS: I also have a setup here at this link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zf43m62r/)

Comment: It would be super cool to have a Pareto chart example in dc.js, but it doesn't look like you have completely thought this through, and I am hesitant to do all the work for you. For one thing, obviously the bars and lines can't be sorted differently, because there is only one X axis, so either the bars or the lines would be mislabeled. Next, the bars should be sorted by the total time within each reason, i.e. the grouped values not the rows.

Comment: Going by [the definition of Pareto chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart), it looks like the line chart should be cumulative. Crossfilter doesn't do that natively, but it's another thing you can do [with fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#accumulate-values). I'd suggest using only one group, sort and accumulate the group using fake groups, creating multiple fields in the output. Then use accessors to pull the data for each part of the composite. Please iterate on this and update your question if you get stuck.

Comment: Okay, I was curious so I went ahead with an answer. Please lmk if it works for you. If so, it would be great to add it to the dc.js examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need a group that computes the total time for each category ("reason"), sorts the computes the contribution of each item, and accumulates the contributions for the line chart.

We can put this logic into a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) that computes everything at once:

```
function pareto_group(group, groupall) { // 1
    return {
      all: function() { // 2
        var total = groupall.value(), // 3
            cumulate = 0; // 4
        return group.all().slice(0) // 5
          .sort((a,b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value)) // 6
          .map(({key,value}) => ({ // 7
            key,
            value: {
              value,
              contribution: value/total,
              cumulative: (cumulate += value/total)
            }
          }))
      }
    };
}
var pg = pareto_group(grp1_, allTime_);
```

1. We need an ordinary group and a groupall for the total as inputs
2. A "fake group" is an object that implements `.all()` and returns an array of `{key, value}` pairs
3. We need the current total over all categories in order to compute the contribution of each category
4. We will accumulate the contributions as we go from left to right
5. We'll take the original group's `.all()`, copying the array using `.slice(0)`
6. Sort in descending order by value
7. ... and generate a new array, with the same keys, but with the value augmented with the individual and cumulative contribution

Initializing the chart requires some obscure workarounds. I won't go too deep into this, except to say that yes this is more complicated than you would think.

```
chart
 .width(768)
        .height(480)
        .x(d3.scaleBand())
        .elasticX(true)
        .ordering(kv => -kv.value.value)
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .group(pg)
        ._rangeBandPadding(1)
        .yAxisLabel("The Y Axis")
        .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .compose([
            dc.barChart(chart)
                .dimension(dim_)
                .barPadding(1)
                .gap(1)
                .centerBar(true)
                .clipPadding(10)
                .group(pg, "Contribution", kv => kv.value.value),
            dc.lineChart(chart) 
                .dimension(dim_)
                .colors('red')
                .group(pg, "Cumulative", kv => Math.floor(kv.value.cumulative*100))
                .useRightYAxis(true)
                .dashStyle([2,2])
            ])
        .brushOn(false);
        
 chart.rightYAxis().tickFormat(d => d + '%')
```

Note that we are turning on [elasticX](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX__anchor) in order to get the chart to reread the X scale domain each redraw.

[Most of the special cases involve ordinal charts](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/662#issuecomment-150097143).

Here is a screenshot:

[image: pareto chart]

And [here is a demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/dfpnh3yb/1/).

Comment: This looks perfect. It looks legit to go on samples as well. One clarification, if you are willing to post this then the fake group must be custom isn't (If they are going to create a Pareto chart) ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. This fake group should work with any group and groupAll that use simple numeric values - does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that fake group works on numeric values. My question is if users want Pareto they will have to implement the fake group (pareto_group) which is specific to their use case. I was wondering if we could make this generic or Pareto itself a chart type as such, you know better.

Comment: I also tried to combine this with other charts to see if it works fine when the drill-down filter is applied, it seems to be bricking. https://jsfiddle.net/1hfxy5e6/1/

Comment: Unless I missed something, the fake group is generic - it will work with any group and groupAll that return plain numeric values. Yes users will have to copy and paste the function, but this is already true of all fake group solutions. I don't think it merits a chart type but I might publish an example.

Comment: Your new fiddle uses the same dimension for both charts, so nothing should happen when it's filtered. Using `dim_.groupAll()` instead of `ndx_.groupAll()` (so that the chart doesn't observe its own filters) stops the line from flying off into space: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/njgumso7/4/

Comment: Okay, I implemented an actual filter situation and discovered a bug - it's illegal to modify the result of `group.all()`, so the data needs to be copied. Updated fiddle with pie chart on speed in my answer above.

Comment: Now if you check this https://jsfiddle.net/xu8Lgm9b/1/ the filter seems to work incorrectly. The line goes random after a couple of filters and resets applied on the second chart.

Comment: You need `elasticX(true)` so that the chart will reread the X domain each redraw. I've updated my answer and fiddle.